# Download error, passing the 100% mark

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I'm from India and tonight (friday 20 june 2014) at around 10:58pm a sight happened to my downloading notification bar. I was downloading ESPN FC FOOTBALL AND WORD CUP app and suddenly after reaching 100%.
And time 0 seconds left the download kept on going and as it passed the 100% mark the time started to go in negative and this continued for about 6-7 minutes.
Please let me know if there is a problem in my android device or it's an error from the play store.
After some time it ultimately installed the app but it kept on closing automatically. I uninstalled it and when I tried to install it again from play store it downloaded but after reaching 100% it said 'a fatal error occurred 961'.
I was using a MOTO G XT1033, non-rooted.

Here are the images:
[image][image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the app. Did you contact the developer?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 961 appears when there is a misconfiguration of system files on the Google Play store. It is happening when downloading,
updating and upgrading mobile applications for
Android Operating System.
To fix this issue, follow these steps.

1. Go to settings
2. Apps
3. All and clear the cache
4. Clear data for google play store
5. Go to settings
6. Accounts and sync
7. Remove all the synced accounts
8. Open google play and register your id again

If this won`t work, you could do reset for Google
Play Store. Here how it do.

1. Go to Setting
2. Click Application or Apps
3. Click Manage Application
4. You will see downloaded, running, all, on SD
   card.
5. Select All
6. Choose Google service frame
7. Choose force stop,
8. Clear data.
9. Restart.

This will reset the Google Play Store and you can
start downloading Apps as normal again.

Comment: Thanks Dhaval.s .Itbtotally worked for me but still one question. Why did my seconds went to negative and % over 100%??was this because of the error 961?

Comment: Actually due to the error, the android system thought that the download was not completed. Android calculates remaining time by using remaining MB to be downloaded and the current download speed. As the remaining MB was not decreasing(due to error), the time started to go in negative. Remaining time is just an integer for Android so it went in negative.